# Should I use "that"?

Tags: sentence-construction, conjunctions, relative-pronouns, mathematics

I was wondering that which of the following is better?

> From Theorem XXX we obtain YYY is red color...

or

> From Theorem XXX we obtain that YYY is red color...

Should I put "that" after obtain?

Comment: Presence of 'that' makes it a bit less colloquial.

Comment: *To **obtain** that [some fact is true]* sounds dated/starchy to me. It may be peculiarly preserved in the "jargon" of scientific researchers, mathematicians, etc., but in normal speech I think ***ascertain*** or ***establish*** are more natural. You should normally include ***that*** before stating the fact itself, to help your audience parse the text.

Comment: Could you supply the complete sentence?

Comment: @snailboat This is the complete sentence. I just replace the part after "obtain that" by a simple sentence YYY is read color. The original part is a long and very theoretical statement contains complex math symbols.

Comment: If the part after *obtain* takes the shape of a formula rather than an English clause, I think the answer is different.

Comment: @snailboat how different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct. However, in this case, reading "From Theorem XXX we obtain YYY is red color" can be confusing at first. When first read, your brain might jump to "From Theorem XXX we obtain YYY" by itself. By including "that", it tells you that an entire clause is coming.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>[I believe the use of **colour** as is in your sentence is actually wrong.]</sub>

So the question here is whether to remove the conjunction **that** or to retain it.

Here it is optional, and the writer/speaker has the liberty to either use it or omit it without affecting the meaning of the sentence.

> Omission of the conjunction that is acceptable, not only in informal
>   contexts, e.g.
>
> > *They understood (that) this was an errand of mercy*. 
> >  
> >     *I would hate to feel (that) we were corrupting you.*
>
> But self-evidently it must be retained in some of the examples cited
>   in the first paragraph above. When the conjunction that is part of the
>   correlative pairs *so ... that*, *such... that*, *now ... that* (or
>   *so that*, etc.), it is normally retained in formal writing but is sometimes omitted in informal contexts, e.g.
>
> > *What would he do now (that) he had missed him in Toulouse?* 
> >     *The heat was up so high (that) almost everyone took off their coats.*
>
> *That* may not be omitted, however, if a phrase or clause intervenes between the verb and it, e.g.
>
> > *I am saying, am I not, that I no longer loved Kioyok.*

<sub>**Reference -** The New Fowler's Modern English Usage</sub>